# Adding and removing properties from java object

Tags: java

How can i achieve this in java. i have an object which has `properties`.

```
public class Object {

    private final Credentials Credentials;
    private final int PageSize;
    private final int PageStart;
    private final int DefaultFilterId;

    public Object(Credentials Credentials, int PageSize, int PageStart, 
int DefaultFilterId) {
            this.Credentials = Credentials;
            this.PageSize = PageSize;
            this.PageStart = PageStart;
            this.DefaultFilterId = DefaultFilterId;
       }

    }
```

Now i am forming a this object like this

```
Object obj = new Object(args);
```

At some point i need the same Object, with new `properties` added but removing `some`.

I do something like this in javascript.

```
var myCars=new Array();
myCars[0]="Saab";
myCars[1]="Volvo";
myCars[2]="BMW";

delete myCars[1]; or myCars.splice(1,1);
```

Comment: You should not name your class `Object`.

Comment: You may like this: http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Object {

    private Credentials credentials;
    private int PageSize;
    private int PageStart;
    private int DefaultFilterId;

    public Object(Credentials credentials, int PageSize, int PageStart, int DefaultFilterId) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.PageSize = PageSize;
        this.PageStart = PageStart;
        this.DefaultFilterId = DefaultFilterId;
    }

    // do that for the properties you want to be able to modify
    public void setCredentials(Credentials newCredentials) {
         this.credentials = newCredentials;
    }

}
```

And you use that:

```
object.setCredentials(yourNewCredentials)
```

Also, you shouldn't name your object "Object", it's the base class for all the classes in Java.

Answer (score 3):

put all your instances of your object in a collection, and then you can delete it from the collection.

```
List<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<YourObject>();
YourObject obj1 = new YourObject("abc");
list.add(obj1);
YourObject obj2 = new YourObject("xyz");
list.add(obj2);
```

now both your objects are inside a list . 
later you can use the remove method an remove them.

```
 list.remove(obj1);
```

and just a pointer, its a bad practice to name your class as `Object` as all java classes `extend` from `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t do that in java. The best approximation is to use HashTable or similar.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put("key", value);
```

Comment: Please be more specific, this is not an answer to the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

You could add an ArrayList as private property to your class. And than build access-functions that allow you to add and delete entries.
You can't do it exactly like in JavaScript.